# POST data while when getting JSON with SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, post

I'm developing an iOS app with Xcode and Swift.

I'm getting JSON data with [SwiftyJSON.swift](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) and the following code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var dict = NSDictionary()

    @IBOutlet weak var firstLb: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondLb: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let urlString = "http://example.com/showUserInfo.php"

        if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {

            if let data = try? NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: []) {

                let json = JSON(data: data)

                print(json)

                let f = json[0]["name"].stringValue

                let s = json[0]["age"].stringValue

                firstLb.text = f

                secondLb.text = s
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That works fine but I want to be able to post to my PHP script. (My PHP script is ready for it. It can receive POST data and handle it.)

I normally use the following code to POST data to PHP:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://example.com/showUserInfo.php")!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let postString = "username=MyUserName"
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

That means: I know how to get data with JSON and I know how to POST a value to PHP. But unfortunately I'm not able to combine both.

Does anybody know how to combine them? How to POST a value to a PHP script where getting the JSON data?

Comment: you can post your PHP code for more help.

Comment: Why that? PHP code contains `$username = $_POST['username'];`. How can I POST a value from my Swift code to my PHP script?

Comment: David, you got it wrong. Show us your attempt on how to post data. Explain, what isn't working and we will help you. This isn't a can "I haz code" site.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I updated my question. Can you help me?

Comment: With `NS(Mutable)URLRequest`, you are in the good path, but don't use the `postString`. You better use `let params = ["username":"MyUserName"], request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params options:0)`, or something like that (it may not compile, I don't speak Swift), or use the SwiftyJSON (since you use it) equivalent method to transform a Dictionary into JSON Data.

Comment: issue resolved?

Comment: Hi @Mr.UB, thanks for asking. Unfortunately it's still not solved. I still wasn't able to do that. Can you help me please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To post data to Server you should use In-build APIs, or you can use a very famous library called : [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

Sample Code:

```
    let params:[String:AnyObject] = [
        "foo" : 1,
        "bar" : 2
    ]

    request(.POST,  "URL", parameters: params)
        .responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .Success(let JSON):
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")

            case .Failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
    }
```

Comment: I prefer a non-library solution. Do you know one?

Comment: @David Alamofire is pretty much industry standard... Why do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Sajjon I prefer custom solutions and I don't want to use CocoaPod. Or is there a way to install Alamofire without CocoaPod?

Comment: Then you can use NSURLSession. But the probability on single developer writing better a HTTPClient on her/his own, than written by the whole open source community is pretty low... This is why I highly recommend Alamofire.

Comment: Yes, you can install Alamofire without cocoapods, just drag and drop the "Source" folder of the Alamofire Project. Don't forget to set target and copy items if required while copying folder.

Comment: What do you mean with "set target"?

Comment: Did u copy the files into your project?

Comment: Hey @Mr.UB, sorry for my late reply. I made the following: I drag&dropped the whole "Source" folder from "Alamofire-master" into the left site bar in Xcode (project navigator). Destination: Copy items if needed. Is there more to do to use Alamofire?

Comment: Do you see any compiles error now? If not then you can run api with `request` instead of `Alamofire.request`.

Comment: Try above code. Replace URL with your URL and parameters with yours, you can set `parameters: nil` if there are no parameters.

Comment: I did. I'm getting `Use of unresolved identifier 'Alamofire'` when using your code.

Comment: at this line: `Alamofire.request(.POST,  "URL", parameters: params)`?

Comment: Yes, at his line.

Comment: Dont use `Alamofire.request`, just use `request`.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your file inspector to see how you imported the Alamofire Source code?

Comment: http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=42f25f-1473759560.jpg and http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=7196fe-1473759570.jpg

Comment: try this code and let me know if the problem persists: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4JO_QKEBIHoOTRLLTNrV3ROZ28

Comment: I took the `Source` folder from `AlamofireManual` and I turned the Source folder in Xcode from blue to yellow by creating a group and importing the files. But, it seems only to work with iOS 8 or higher. Is that right?

Comment: @Mr.UB And what to do if I want to support iOS 7, too?

Comment: Its may be due to Alamofire being written in Swift.

Comment: You might need to use older Alamofire versions.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But still a question: How to output the data? This doesn't work: `let name = json[0]["name"].stringValue`

Comment: what's your server response?

Comment: `JSON: ({ name = "David"; age = 19;})`

Comment: are you getting data inside `( )` parenthesis?

Comment: Yes, I do that.

Comment: Try this:  `print(JSON.objectAtIndex(0).valueForKey("name"))`

Comment: I finally found the working solution with your help. I updated it in your "answer".